# Graph Api Explorer Not Working in IE8

Tags: facebook-graph-api, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, explorer

I'm using the Graph API Explorer to help debug my app. All I'm doing is calling /me/, but this does not seem to be working in **IE7 & 8**.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me

The API Explorer is getting the following error:

> An error has occurred in the script on this page
>
> Line: 5
>   Char: 4611
>   Error: Object doesn't support this action
>   Code: 0
>   URL: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me

I'm not sure if the code in my app is not working or if this error is displaying because the API Explorer is messed up. Anyone experiencing the same issue?

I've also been trying to call "/me/friends/" and have also received the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error message looks like a JavaScript error, which would suggest that the API Explorer is not Internet-Explorer compatible. I did a cursory search but was unable to find any information on the Graph API Explorer's browser compatibility.

I would suggest filing [a bug on Facebook's bugtracker](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs) and adding it as a comment here.

Comment: LOL Unfortunately, it looks like their bug tracker isn't submitting either!